# Custom Dialog display very small in xamarin.android

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I am displaying custom dialog in my xamarin android app.

it display but it display very small.

I want to set height and width for dialog dynamically according to the device size..

I found the solution but solution is for android..

here is solution from android

```
  WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
            lp.copyFrom(dialog2.getWindow().getAttributes());
            lp.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
            lp.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
            lp.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
            dialog2.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
```

I want to set same functionality but i want to it in xamarin.

How could i do this in xamarin

Comment: I will check and update soon

Comment: Thanks A lot sir Its working

Answer (score 1):

Usage in Xamarin like this :

```
WindowManagerLayoutParams lp = new WindowManagerLayoutParams(); 
lp.CopyFrom(dialog2.Window.Attributes); 
lp.Width = WindowManagerLayoutParams.MatchParent; 
lp.Height = WindowManagerLayoutParams.WrapContent; 
lp.Gravity = GravityFlags.Center; 
dialog2.Window.Attributes = lp;
```

Answer (score 0):

Theres a lot of content i don't know if you need it all but its there :)

On my side, I wanted to dynamically set the height of my content based on its size. If the content is smaller, I want to use "wrap content" to adjust the height accordingly. If the content is too large, I want to limit it to a maximum of 90%.

```cs
 Dialog alert = new Dialog(this);
            View view = LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.my_content, drawer, false);
            alert.SetContentView(view);

//Get display pixel width
            int displayWidth = (int)(Resources.DisplayMetrics.WidthPixels * 0.9);
            int displayHeight = (int)(Resources.DisplayMetrics.HeightPixels * 0.9);

alert.Window.SetLayout(displayWidth, displayHeight);
```

this is the part to recalculate it

```cs
 alert.Window.DecorView.Post(() =>
            {
                //put whatever you want in this
                int content1Height = 100;
                int content2Height = 200;
                int content3Height = 300;

                int totalViewHeight = content1Height + content2Height + content3Height;


               
                int heightUsed = System.Math.Min(displayHeight, totalViewHeight);
                alert.Window.SetLayout(displayWidth, heightUsed);
            });
```